# Bash how to minus the number of guesses each time the user inputs?

Tags: bash

```
while true
do
    if [ $userinput = 1 ];
    then
        guesses=10
        (( answer = RANDOM % 20 ))
        read -p "Guess the number between 1-20 if you can $answer : " input
        if [ $input != $answer ];
        then
            (( guesses=guesses-1 ))
            echo "Wrong answer! You got ${guesses} left!"
        else
            echo "Correct answer! You had ${guesses} left. Lucky you!"
            read -p "${name}, would you like to continue playing or not [Yes/No]? " decide
            if [ $decide = "Yes" ];
            then
                continue
            else
                echo -e "${Red}Bye bye!"
```

Example:

guess=10

User inputs 2 guesses then program has to minus those 2 guesses from total of 10 guesses, in that case, 10-2=8 guesses left. **How to do this?**

Comment: I agree with @melpomene.  Please remove the picture and add your code directly to the content of your post!

Comment: Post updated. Picture removed, code added directory to the content.

Comment: Please format your code block so that each line of code begins with four spaces.  This will improve the appearance of your code and add highlighting.

Comment: If `(( guesses = guesses - 1 ))` didn't work and you had to change to `let`, your shell wasn't actually `bash`. Moreover, if you want something that will reliably work on shells that aren't bash, `guesses=$(( guesses - 1 ))` is more widely supported than `let`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are specifically using the Bash shell, then the `let` builtin is what you want.

The `let` builtin is a clean way to perform integer arithmetic in Bash.  You should read the output of `help let` to get a better picture of how it works.

The two lines you circled in your linked picture could be written as follows:

```
let guesses=10  # Set "guesses" to 10
let guesses-=1  # Decrement "guesses" by 1
```

Most proficient Bash hackers would write these operations in this manner.  You could also use the post-decrement operator.

```
let guesses--  # Also decrement "guesses" by 1
```

This may look a little cleaner to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work out. It said "guesses-=1": command not found.

Comment: @KristenUngur: That is because you are setting `guesses` to 10 each time your loop executes.  Move the definition of `guesses` to above the `while` statement.

Comment: Omg! It worked! Thank you very much! I have less than 15 reputation so I can't upvote it :(. But this is the answer I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `(( guesses = guesses - 1 ))` is **completely** valid syntax in bash. More pointedly, `let` is present as legacy support for backwards compatibility with pre-POSIX (which is to say, pre-1992) shells; there's no reason to encourage its use in new code. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: ...moreover, `guesses=$(( guesses - 1 ))` is POSIX-standardized, and thus guaranteed to be present on all modern (standard-compliant) shells.

Comment: ...see also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete; `let` has an entry in the very last table.

Answer (score 2):

The **only** necessary change is moving `guesses=10` out of your loop, such that it's run only once (when your script is starting).

---

As for best-practice decrement forms, a terser bash-only approach (albeit no more or less valid than your existing implementation) would look like:

```
(( guesses-- ))
```

...whereas a more portable approach (compatible with all POSIX-family shells) is:

```
guesses=$(( guesses - 1 ))
```